# Correct svn timestamps of revision range

Tags: svn, timestamp

I didn't notice that the **system time** of my SVN-Server changed (few months ago).

Server time is 5.5 hours in the past, so are my commit timestamps.

Is there any way to correct the timestamps, for a range of revisions?

Something like:
rev.timestamp = rev.timestamp + 5.5 hours?

Answer (score -1):

Your commit's date is defined in the `svn:date` unversioned property (aka revision property) in ISO 8601 format. Therefore, you can write a script that will change the property's value to the one you want.

Here is an example that uses the latest Subversion 1.11.x admin command line tools and assumes that you have local admin rights on the SVN server. You can download the latest tools at https://www.visualsvn.com/downloads/.

1. Dump your current repository's revprops to a file:
   `svnadmin dump-revprops MyRepo -r REV1:REV2 > myrevprops.rpdump`

Replace REV1 and REV2 with first and last revisions that you want to modify.
Here is a sample output of the command:

```
SVN-fs-dump-format-version: 2

UUID: 044999d0-8b80-614c-8958-c042f8e3b5fb

Revision-number: 1
Prop-content-length: 122
Content-length: 122

K 10
svn:author
V 15
Pavel.Lyalyakin
K 8
svn:date
V 27
2019-04-04T17:04:19.559381Z
K 7
svn:log
V 11
Test commit
PROPS-END

* Dumped revision 1.
```

2. Make a backup of your repository and the myrevprops.rpdump file.
3. Modify the svn:date value in the file `myrevprops.rpdump` with a text editor.
4. Run the following command to load new revprops.

   `svnadmin load-revprops MyRepo -r REV1:REV2 < myrevprops.txt`

That's it, you should see the new time should be associated with your commits now.

Comment: You cannot edit Subversion dump files in text editor: while they may look like text files, actually they are binary files. Proper solution is to use `svnlook propget` and `svnadmin setrevprop`.